# How to open the SCCM Configuration Manager in VB - Visual Studio 2015

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, configurationmanager, sccm

I'm creating a tool in VB using Visual Studio 2015 and I'm having some issues with forcing one item on a menu strip when clicked to open the `SCCM Configuration Manager`.

So far I've tried:

Option 1

```
Dim ProcID As Integer 
ProcID = Shell("control smscfgrc", AppWinStyle.NormalFocus)
```

Option 2

```
Process.Start("cmd.exe", "control smscfgrc")
```

Option 3

```
Dim p as Process = new Process()
Dim pi as ProcessStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
pi.Arguments = "control smscfgrc"
pi.FileName = "cmd.exe"
p.StartInfo = pi
```

Option 4

```
Shell=("control smscfgrc", 0)
```

None of the above work, they just open the console but nothing else.

If I open a regular `cmd` window using `"windows + R"` and type the command `"control smscfgrc"` it open the `SCCM Configuration Manager` as it should.

I really need this to complete my tool, any help is much appreciated!

Thank you for the time you took to read this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not a guru with VS nor VB, but your commands to open `cmd.exe` looks incorrect. You need to add a `/c`. The command in the *Run* window (<kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>) would look like this ...

```
cmd.exe /c control smscfgrc
```

Of course, `control` is actually `control.exe`, so you don't even need `cmd.exe`:

```
control.exe smscfgrc
```

Tested and confirmed that this opens the *Configuration Manager Properties* window from the *Run* windows on my computer.

You also may need the full path to `control.exe`. I would use environment variables; I think this is how it would be done in VB:

```
Dim control_exe As String
control_exe = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SystemRoot") & "\System32\control.exe"
```

You will automatically get redirected to `SysWOW64` if running on as a 32-bit process on a 64-bit OS.

### Option 2

```
Process.Start(control_exe, "smscfgrc")
```

### Option 3

```
Dim p as Process = new Process()
Dim pi as ProcessStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
pi.Arguments = "smscfgrc"
pi.FileName = control_exe
p.StartInfo = pi
```

Comment: Got it to work using 'Process.Start("control.exe", "smscfgrc.cpl")'
Many thanks!!