# Open Configuration Manager from VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, cmd, sccm

Good day everyone!

well Im out of options atm, maybe you guys can throw me a bone in the right direction.

Im trying to open the SCCM configuration manager via vb.NET, I`ve tried the solutions on many forums including a 2016 SO thread: [How to open the SCCM Configuration Manager in VB - Visual Studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36205522/how-to-open-the-sccm-configuration-manager-in-vb-visual-studio-2015)

so far, the thing just wont open, I tried to use a cmd from inside the vb.net app, this result in the cmd window opening, but not the actual ConfigM window.

Any ideas on how to open this from vb.net aside the provided on the other thread?

any help is greately appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the code you've tried?

Comment: From what I've seen in the example they call SMSCFGRC.cpl without path, meaning it is fully dependent on your path variable. What I would do is first check where the file is located (default would be C:\windows\ccm\SMSCFGRC.cpl) then check whether it starts via "run" in windows (win+r) with the full path. If this is the case try to launch it from vb with the full path. (normally C:\windows\ccm\SMSCFGRC.cpl should be enough but if it is not maybe try for both C:\windows\system32\control.exe C:\windows\ccm\SMSCFGRC.cpl).